# Memory assigned to strings

Tags: c#, string

I know that `string`s in C# are immutable i.e. when I change the value of a `string` variable a new `string` variable with the same name is created with the new value and the older one is collected by GC. Am I right?

```
string s1 = "abc";
s1 = s1.Substring(0, 1);
```

If what I said is right, then my doubt is if a new `string` is created, then is it created in the same memory location?

Comment: If without the word string infront of s1 it would be the same.But with string I don't know

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years I think I put the string in the second line by mistake. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> if a new string is created, then is it created in the same memory location?

No, a separate `string` object is created, in a separate bit of memory.

You're then replacing the value of `s1` with a reference to the newly-created string. That *may or may not* mean that the original string can be garbage collected - it depends on whether anything else has references to it. In the case of a string constant (as in your example, with a string literal) I *suspect* that won't be garbage collected anyway, although it's an implementation detail.

If you have:

```
string text = "original";
text = text.Substring(0, 5);
text = text.Substring(0, 3);
```

then the *intermediate* string created by the first call to `Substring` will be eligible for garbage collection, because nothing else refers to it. That doesn't mean it will be garbage collected immediately though, and it certainly doesn't mean that its memory will be reused for the string created by the final line.

Comment: @oleksii: I think that would add more complexity than is required.